# Android SDK 33 - Image saved to app folder but not visible in gallery

Tags: android, kotlin

I try to save image from my app to the gallery using button. It does saved in **Android/data/com.myapp/files/Pictures** but not visible in gallery

Here are my manifest file permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

My code of button

```
saveButton1.setOnClickListener {
            saveImage(imageView1)
        }
```

I'm not checking or asking any other permission

```
 private fun saveImage(imageView: ImageView) {
        val bitmap = (imageView.drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
        val imageName = "${System.currentTimeMillis()}.png"
        val imageFile = File("${getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)}", imageName)

        val fos = FileOutputStream(imageFile)
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos)
        fos.flush()
        fos.close()

        // Scan the saved image file to make it visible in the gallery.
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
            this,
            arrayOf(imageFile.absolutePath),
            arrayOf("image/png"),
            null
        )
        Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

What could be the possible issue and your suggestion for this? Please treat me like a learner developer.